# Get list of files in folder with specific set of extensions as a comma separated string

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a PowerShell script that needs to perform a number of different operations (based on the received parameters) including returning as a comma-separated list of sub-folders within a folder and (different action) a comma-separated list of files within a sub-folder where the files would have one within a pre-defined set of extensions.

So far, I was able to get the list of sub-folders (found suitable examples) as well as a list of files with **one specific extension** (both as comma-separated strings). What I failed to achieve was to provide two or more possible extensions.

The list of subfolders is returned using the following command:

```
$Folders_List=(Get-ChildItem ./All_Subfolders/ -Directory | % Name) -join ','
```

To get the list of files with one specific extensions:

```
$Files_List=(Get-ChildItem -path .\All_Subfolders\Subfolder_1\ -filter *.js -file -ErrorAction silentlycontinue -recurse | % Name) -join ','
```

As soon as attempt to define more than one possible extension, things break and I get error messages (depending on what I try).

Some of the attempts included changing `*,js` to `(*.js , *.css)`, the same without parenthesis and/or comma, etc.

Comment: Use `-Include` instead of `-Filter`. `-Filter` only support a single string as argument.

Comment: BINGO @SantiagoSquarzon!!!! THANKS!!!

Comment: @FDavidov: would you consider accepting the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

I would try using the `-Include` parameter instead of the `-Filter`. I would try something like this:

```
$Files_List = (Get-ChildItem -Path ".\All_Subfolders\Subfolder_1\" -Include *.txt, *.vbs -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse) -join ','
```

It worked fine for me also with multiple extensions.

Comment: Thank you Hydro for your answer. Please check Santiago's comment to the question which, in fact, suggests exactly the same solution.